# How to set different Laravel 5 storage and cache path local vs production?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I can't find any good answers on how to best set different storage and cache paths for my Laravel 5 application based on which environment it's running on.

I specially want to change the storage path and the cache path.

At the moment the config/cache.php has a line like this:

```
'path'   => storage_path().'/framework/cache',
```

I want to change that to "/www/app-cache/" for production environment only.

And I want to change the default storage_path to "/www/app-store/" for production environment only.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

At the moment I have created a new application class which extends the old one, like this:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class XXXApplication extends Application
{
    public function storagePath()
    {
        if($this->environment('production')) {
            return '/www/app-store/';
        }

        return parent::storagePath();
    }
}
```

Is that a smart way to do it, and if so, how do I also change the cache path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, in you local env, you are using the .env file.

So, you can do the following in your config/cache.php file

```
'path' => env('CACHE_PATH', storage_path().'/framework/cache');
```

If in your .env there is a CACHE_PATH variable, your app will use it.
If not, it will use by default the other one specified in the second parameter.

Do the some for you storage path in app.php

Comment: Is this a good way to do it? "public function storagePath() {
        return env('STORAGE_PATH', parent::storagePath());
    }" or is there a better way without extending the Application class?

Comment: It's better to override the configuration instead of doing a custom function : for readability and code comprehension.

Comment: Can I just add the storage path in the config/app.php, I don't think it's specified there by default.